# Outputting nested scripts to a file

Tags: linux, unix, system

I have a file that calls another file within it and output to the screen whole bunch of data which I would like to save to a separate file. 
I am aware of the command ./script1 > file.txt, to save script1's outputs to a file, but I noticed that if I have a script lets call it nested_script, which is called from script1, it's output will not get saved to file.txt.. I was searching for a way around this, and was wondering if anyone could help!

Thank you

Comment: if nested_script is also sending its output to STDOUT (terminal) then that will also be stored in your log/txt file if redirected using ">" or ">>", you just need to redirect the output of your main script only.

Comment: hmm ok I guess I will recheck my code,, Thanks narendra